# git fetch --recurse-submodules=yes fails with two levels of nesting

Tags: git

*Edit. This question is not relevant at the moment, because the created minimal example does not capture something central about the corresponding real-world case. I can not delete the question, so just ignore this question for the time being.*

I have a complicated real-world case where `git fetch --recurse-submodules=yes` fails with two levels of nesting of submodules, while fetching in the same repo tree at level one works fine (between any two levels). A minimal reproducible example follows:

Running `gmake` in a dir with the following `Makefile` creates three local repos.

```makefile
define create-repo =
mkdir $@
cd $@ && git init && touch $@-file && git add $@-file && git commit -m "initial commit" && git remote add origin $(CURDIR)/$@
endef

default: top-repo

sub-repo-level-1:
    $(create-repo)

sub-repo-level-2:
    $(create-repo)

top-repo: sub-repo-level-1 sub-repo-level-2
    $(create-repo)
    cp -r sub-repo-level-1 $@/
    cp -r sub-repo-level-2 $@/sub-repo-level-1/
    cd $@/sub-repo-level-1 && git submodule add ./sub-repo-level-2 sub-repo-level-2 && git commit -m "added submodule level 2"
    cd $@ && git submodule add ./sub-repo-level-1 sub-repo-level-1 && git commit -m "added submodule level 1"
```

The created directory tree is shown below.

```bash
$ tree
.
├── Makefile
├── sub-repo-level-1
│   └── sub-repo-level-1-file
├── sub-repo-level-2
│   └── sub-repo-level-2-file
└── top-repo
    ├── sub-repo-level-1
    │   ├── sub-repo-level-1-file
    │   └── sub-repo-level-2
    │       └── sub-repo-level-2-file
    └── top-repo-file
```

`top-repo` has now nested submodules. These submodules have their remotes set to be the repos created at the same directory tree level as `top-repo`. In the real-world case the remotes are "true remotes."

Now, `git fetch --recurse-submodules=yes` works with one level of nesting, but fails at two levels. First, no problem with one level of nesting between the bottom two levels of the repo tree.

```bash
$ (cd top-repo/sub-repo-level-1/; git fetch --recurse-submodules=yes)
From /tmp/submodule-fetch/sub-repo-level-1
 * [new branch]      main       -> origin/main
Fetching submodule sub-repo-level-2
From /tmp/submodule-fetch/sub-repo-level-2
 * [new branch]      main       -> origin/main
```

Second, shown at once, making the one-level transition from `top-repo` to `sub-repo-level-1` works just fine, but trying to go down two levels `top-repo` -> `sub-repo-level-1` -> `sub-repo-level-2` results in an error.

```bash
$ (cd top-repo; git fetch --recurse-submodules=yes)
From /tmp/submodule-fetch/top-repo
 * [new branch]      main       -> origin/main
Fetching submodule sub-repo-level-1
Could not access submodule 'sub-repo-level-2'
Errors during submodule fetch:
    sub-repo-level-1
```

*Why does this happen?*

Output of `git submodule status --recursive`:

```bash
$ (cd top-repo; git submodule status --recursive)
 90daaf3e00ed8ea57af77019d03d58357ae5cdf9 sub-repo-level-1 (heads/main)
 caa3896c80802299d5b224bcc84a7c68a6cb1a1c sub-repo-level-1/sub-repo-level-2 (heads/main)
```

And git version:

```bash
$ git --version
git version 2.43.0
```

Answer (score 2):

You want to run this command inside of `top-repo`:

```bash
git submodule absorbgitdirs
```

After that `git submodule` commands appear to start working correctly.

This command moves the `.git` directories you manually set up under `top-repo/.git/modules/`:

- `top-repo/sub-repo-level-1/.git` --> `.git/modules/sub-repo-level-1`
- `top-repo/sub-repo-level-1/sub-repo-level-2/.git` --> `.git/modules/sub-repo-level-1/modules/sub-repo-level-2`

Unfortunately, how you have it set up, each submodule's pull URL is still set to its own directory, so they're all pulling from themselves. The `absorbgitdirs` command does not correct this. Use `git remote -v` to check the URL and `git remote set-url origin <URL>` to update it.

### Further Comments

I think you're not fully understanding how git submodules work or are supposed to work in Git.

1. When you add a submodule it adds a bare git repo directory for that submodule under the parent project's `.git/modules` directory.

```bash
git init
mkdir -p path/to/my
git submodule add https://example.com/foo.git path/to/my/foomodule
# Repo files for foo.git are now located in .git/modules/path/to/my/foomodule
```

The fact you have multiple `.git` directories around your `top-repo` directory means your code didn't set up real submodules, it set up some hybrid or abomination. `git submodule absorbgitdirs` appears to fix this, however.

2. `git submodule add` requires the submodule source be a non-`file://` URL... for some reason (`/path/bla` is shorthand for `file:///path/bla`).

Comment: Kudos for the solution (which worked). However, this does not explain the root cause. There are two ways to add a submodule: either from a remote repo (new way) or from a directory (old way). The old way preserves a directory `.git` inside the submodule (it remains "an independent repo" by itself); the new way creates a file `.git` which points to a location. Fetching recursively works at all levels with the new way, and `absorbgitdirs`converts from old to new. But why does the old way *not* allow recursive fetching over multiple levels?

Comment: @jhu How you have the submodules set up, fetch doesn't do anything for the reason I mention in my answer; the remote URL is set to its own directory. That being said, I would bet it's failing because you've set the submodules' remote URLs to relative paths, e.g. `./sub-repo-level-1`, instead of `/path/to/sub-repo-level-1`.

Comment: I know from the real-world case that the way the remote is set up is not the issue: the issue is the fact that in one way of setting up uses a `.git` dir for the submodule, the other way creates a `.git` file. In the real-world case all remote repos are on servers. I will need to modify my example here so that the remote is not set to directory itself. I will get back once I have the time to do this.

Comment: I ran some additional tests, and you are correct that in this minimal example setting the remotes of the submodules *not* to point at themselves solves the problem. Unfortunately this is not the issue in the real-world case. So there is something in the real-world case that is not captured by this example. I guess I have no choice but to go back to the drawing board. Thanks for the input!